# Get real-time notifications from Gmail and Google calendar on slack with PubSub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, webhooks, slack, google-cloud-pubsub

I try to get real-time notifications on my slack channel from google calendar and gmail apis.

I already created a Pub-Sub account and I want to add a push subscription on my topic with a slack incoming webhook url but when I try to add it, I got :

*The supplied HTTP URL is not registered in the subscription's parent project*

Answer (score 1):

I've tried the same thing and it seems that first, you need to verify ownership of your webhook domain.
You would do it here :
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/domainverification

if you would own the slack domain, which I don't think you do...and I don't either...unfortunately I haven't found a solution to circumvent this.

"You need to verify domain ownership to allow webhook notifications to be sent to your external domains. Google verifies that the user owns each of the listed domains via Search Console."

Answer (score 0):

iv the same problem.

Try with this https://github.com/Spencer-Easton/Apps-Script-Gmail-Push-Notifications

or see : https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/advanced#push_endpoints

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/advanced#register) explains, in the article "Cloud Pub/Sub > Documentation > Advanced Configuration", in the section "Register Endpoints", how to register endpoints not on App Engine or not on the same cloud project. You'll need to very that you own the domain and register it.